# ErrorException Illegal string offset 'hex'

Tags: laravel, laravel-6

I keep getting this error:

ErrorException Illegal string offset 'hex'

PHP version:  "php": "^7.2"

Barryvdh version: "barryvdh/laravel-dompdf": "^0.8.6"

```
$pdf = PDF::loadView('layouts.resultsPagePDF',compact("data"));
```

Comment: [this post](https://www.drupal.org/project/entity_print/issues/3134093) suggests that this might be a bug in 0.8.4+ so try reverting to version 0.8.3

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To fix it very fast, Change all non-hex colors to hex colors.

Answer (score 0):

**Here Example**

> Simply added the "#"

**Before:**

```
background: e45716;
color: e45716;
border-bottom: 1px solid e45716;
```

**After:**

```
background: #e45716;
border-bottom: 1px solid #e45716;
```